# Android opengl texture problem - display has messed up with lot of colors

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, android-ndk

I am trying to load a texture on to my android app display, where I am using code from **[this github](https://github.com/richq/glbuffer)**.

I get my pixels messed up completely on the screen, And I have no idea, what's going on. The only thing I change in that code is I have memcpy, which copied uint8_t buffer into s_pixels instead of render_pixels in glbuffer.c file. My frame pixels are in rgb565 format.

Is it somekind of configuration problem or any problem with the way I copy pixels?

**EDIT**

Below is the code :

pictureQ is as below

pictureQ {
uint8_t *data;
int size;
}

```
    memcpy(s_pixels,&(pictureQ[qFirst].data[0]) , 307200);
    //render_pixels(s_pixels);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   // glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 480, 320, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, &(pictureRGBQ[qFirst].data[0]));
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 480, 320, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, s_pixels);

    check_gl_error("glTexSubImage2D");
    glDrawTexiOES(0, 0, 0, s_w, s_h);
    check_gl_error("glDrawTexiOES");
    memset(s_pixels, 0, 307200);
```

Comment: Itd be good if you could attach a screenshot so we could see what "messed up completely" means.

Comment: attached the screenshot of the display.

Comment: Ok, that *is* messed up! Now what's it *supposed* to look like? And what size is your texture?

Comment: it is 480x320p. And it is a proper image. I have posted my code(edited) where I created the texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, It was my mistake, I was passing the data for the pixels instead of the data. Thanks for your response Reuben Scatton.